# Can I Edit the Rig Bones while a Mesh is Bound to it?

Tags: rigging, bones

i have been working with a rigging addon (not rigify) for a special use case for all of my blender life. (ie: i learned blender while using this addon.)  when working with this addon, if i edit the bones of the rig while the mesh is bound to it, the whole thing will be trashed.  because reasons.  (has to do with special data for my special case.)

now, however, i have been working with a non-special rig, and i have to ask... is it okay/safe to edit the rig while meshes are bound to it?

in a specific case, i would dearly love to be able to move the bone heads while the rig/mesh is posed to see what the results are when moving the rotation center of a joint.

or at least not have to unbind my mesh(es), edit the rig, and rebind the mesh(es), if that's not really necessary.

Comment: of course you can, it will just move the center of rotation when you'll animate the bone

Comment: The rig will generally stay intact, but you will break previously stored animations and poses (if existing). You could break it if you move bones that are target of others bones constraints, like IK, dumped track or stretch to.

Comment: awesome, thanks, guys!